# How do I map prism properties to class by CsvHelper?

Tags: c#, wpf, csvhelper

I use Library that CSVHelper and I want to map my csv to my class.

I tried this code but records have no class.

```
using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(MY_FILE_PATH))
using (var csv = new CsvReader(streamReader))
{
    csv.Configuration.HasHeaderRecord = true;
    csv.Configuration.RegisterClassMap<MyClassMapper>();
    var records = csv.GetRecords<MyClassMapper>();
}


public class MyClassMapper : CsvHelper.Configuration.ClassMap<MyClass>
{
    public MyClassMapper()
    {
        Map(x => x.Column1).Index(0);
        Map(x => x.Column2).Index(1);
        Map(x => x.Column3).Index(2);
        Map(x => x.Column4).Index(3);
        Map(x => x.Column5).Index(4);
        Map(x => x.Column6).Index(5);
        Map(x => x.Column7).Index(6);
        Map(x => x.Column8).Index(7);
        Map(x => x.Column9).Index(8);
    }
}
```

This is MyClass code.
I use Prism Library.
I want map to properties.

```
public class MyClass {
    private int column1;
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 0)]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int Column1
    {
    get { return column1; }
    set { this.SetProperty(ref column1, value); }
    }

    //More Properties...

    private int column9;
    public int Column9
    {
    get { return column2; }
    set { this.SetProperty(ref column2, value); }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that the line var records = csv.GetRecords<MyClassMapper>(); is correct? should not it be var records = csv.GetRecords<MyClass>();

Comment: I'm sorry, I mistaked mapper class.
If I use csv.GetRecords<MyClass> then I caught error that error code BC30707.

Comment: I tried it using `csv.GetRecords<MyClass>` and Prism and it seemed worked for me.  I had to set up `MyClass` like this `public class MyClass: Prism.Mvvm.BindableBase`. What does your data look like?